# Expect returns same value

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

I need to be able to return a different password after the first one fails which will be the second time the prompt asks for the same expect value "Password:"

```
(expect -c "

 #exp_internal 1
  set passwords {PASS1 PASS2}
  set index 0 
  set timeout 20
  # Start the session with the input variable and the rest of the hostname
  spawn telnet $host
  set timeout 3 
  expect {
-ex     \"Password:\" {
            send \"[lindex $passwords $index]\r\"
            incr index  
 exp_continue;
  }
  }
```

I just can't get it to work. It looks like there is nothing in the `lindex` send:

```
 -ex     "Password:" {
    send "[lindex  ]\r"
```

Comment: did you try `\r\n` for your End-of-line? Good luck.

Comment: There might be a problem with `\r` being interpreted by bash. Have you tried putting the expect script (i.e., the commands that you feed to `expect -c`) in a different file?

Comment: I'm getting:

    args: should be "lindex list ?index...?"
    while executing
    "lindex  "
    invoked from within

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're using double quotes to group the expect script -- bash is interpreting the `$variables` as *bash variables*. You need to either:

1. use single quotes to delimit the script, or
2. escape all the `\$expect_variables` so bash does not substitute them first.

Comment: Glen you genius! Thanks. I was going crazy and that's all it was.